# Demonstrate AB+C(A+B)=AB+C(A⊕B)

Tags: calculus, boolean-algebra

Please help me demonstrate that **AB+C(A+B)=AB+C(A'B+AB')**. I've tried a couple of times but i always reach **AB=2AB** .

Comment: I don't have experience with boolean algebra, but I don't think these things are equal: What if $A$ and $B$ are both 'true'?

Comment: I dont know ,anyway i found out that i was wrong reaching AB=2AB..so now i have completely no idea

Comment: Oh, I see; if $A$ and $B$ are both 'true' then the expression does work out; the $AB$ at the beginning saves it.

Comment: Our professor basically told us that the equation is true everytime.It doesn't matter if A and B are true or not .. and i really have no idea how to demonstrate it

Answer (score 0):

Not a very rigorous solution, but: the left-hand side is $AB + C(A + B) = AB + BC + CA$. This means that if any two of $A$, $B$, $C$ are true, then the expression is true, otherwise it is false. On the right-hand side, if both $A$ and $B$ are true, then the expression is true. If one of $A$ and $B$ is true, and $C$ is true, then also the expression is true. Otherwise, it is false. Hence the two are equal.